# Image slideshow and refresher

Tags: javascript, image, random

I'm wondering how I could have a JavaScript image rotator/slideshow, that each time it displays each image (for 5 seconds), it refreshes from the last time it has shown.

Also, as something else, but not requiered, I was wondering if it was possible to have a drop-down list of the image locations down the bottom (there are 12 images) that each links to the appropriate image and refreshes it every 3 minutes.

Here's what I have so far. I know it's outdated, but I can't find anything more modern via Google...thanks!

```
var interval = 5; // delay between rotating images (in seconds)
var random_display = 0; // 0 = no, 1 = yes
interval *= 1000;

var image_index = 0;
image_list = new Array();
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23004/1281263292.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23008/1281263293.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23011/1281263293.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23013/1281263294.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23014/1281263294.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23020/1281263295.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23025/1281263296.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23022/1281263296.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23024/1281263296.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23033/1281263298.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23034/1281263298.jpg");
image_list[image_index++] = new imageItem("http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23040/1281263299.jpg");
var number_of_image = image_list.length;
function imageItem(image_location) {
this.image_item = new Image();
this.image_item.src = image_location;
}
function get_ImageItemLocation(imageObj) {
return(imageObj.image_item.src)
}
function generate(x, y) {
var range = y - x + 1;
return Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + x;
}
function getNextImage() {
if (random_display) {
image_index = generate(0, number_of_image-1);
}
else {
image_index = (image_index+1) % number_of_image;
}
var new_image = get_ImageItemLocation(image_list[image_index]);
return(new_image);
}
function rotateImage(place) {
var new_image = getNextImage();
document[place].src = new_image;
var recur_call = "rotateImage('"+place+"')";
setTimeout(recur_call, interval);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "it refreshes from the last time it has shown"?

Comment: So the images refresh, it's not just the same images cycling through, they images need to be regularly updated.

Comment: You say you want a drop-down list.  Is this to open a new page, under your control, to show the refreshing image?  Or to show the source page?  Or to show the image in your original page, in addition to the rotating image?

Comment: can you predict the filenames of future images from the Vic roads page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it... tested in Firefox and a few others.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Camera Slideshow</title>
<style>
#wrapper {
    width:   400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    width:   10000px;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -moz-transition:    all linear 500ms;
    -o-transition:      all linear 500ms;
    transition:         all linear 500ms;
}
.slide {
    float:   left;
    padding: 24px;
}
.slide img {
    width:   352px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="cams" class="">
    <div id="content" class="">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="slideshow" style="left:0;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="list">
            <select id="locations"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
var Images = [
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23004/1281263292.jpg", name: "Kings Way / Sturt St" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23008/1281263293.jpg", name: "Punt Rd / Swan St" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23011/1281263293.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23013/1281263294.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23014/1281263294.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23020/1281263295.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23025/1281263296.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23022/1281263296.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23024/1281263296.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23033/1281263298.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23034/1281263298.jpg", name: "Name of location" },
    { src: "http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23040/1281263299.jpg", name: "WGF / Montague St" }
];
Images.Current = 0;

var App = {
    run: function(){
        var instance = this;

        this.addSlides();

        setInterval(function(){
            instance.refresh();
            instance.rotate();
        }, 5000);

        document.getElementById("locations").onchange = function() {
            var loc = document.getElementById("locations").value;
            if (loc>-1) {
                Images.Current = (loc-1);
                instance.rotate();
            }
        };
    },

    addSlides: function() { //352 x 288
        var limit = Images.length;
        var html  = '';
        var list  = '<option value="-1">Choose a location</option>';

        for (var i=0; i<limit; i++) {
            html += "<div class='slide'>" +
                    "   <img class='img' alt='" + i + "' title='" + Images[i].name + "' src='" + Images[i].src + "' />" +
                    "</div>";
            list += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + Images[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML += html;
        document.getElementById('locations').innerHTML += list;
    },

    refresh: function() {
        var img  = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[Images.Current];
        img.src = Images[Images.Current].src + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
    },

    rotate: function() {
        Images.Current++;
        if (Images.Current == Images.length) { Images.Current = 0; }
        var xpos = (Images.Current==0) ? 0 : Images.Current * -400;
        document.getElementById('slideshow').setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + xpos + 'px;');
    }
};
App.run();
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

A few things...

1. I didn't fill in all the location
   names, but that should be easy
2. The image file name is not imprtant,
   you could use anything, for example:
   http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23008/1281263293.jpg 
   is the same as
   http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/images/23008/hello.jpg
3. There are a number of optimizations you could do but I didn't bother for reasons of time and clarity.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options out there. http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

But if you're talking about actually grabbing the current image at http://livetraffic.vicroads.vic.gov.au/region/23004?expanddiv=group1 then that's a bit different. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm hoping to achieve, which can be done by refreshing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, very simple and infinite amount of photos in a neat array.

```
<script>
slist=[
"image1",
"image2",
"image3"
];
var i=0;
function slideshow(){
i=(i>slist.length-2)?0:i+1; 
document.getElementById("slide").src=slist[i];
setTimeout("slideshow()",3000);
}
</script>

<img src="image1" id="slide">
```

---

Since I made my last post, I made a better script, here it is:
*if you want to add more images, edit the number "3" in the javascript*

```
<style>
div{position:relative}
div>img{opacity:0;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
-webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-moz-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-ms-transition:opacity 1s linear;
-o-transition:opacity 1s linear;
transition:opacity 1s linear}
</style>

<script>
var i=0,a=function(o){document.getElementById("i"+i).style.opacity=o;};
setInterval(function(){a("0");i=(i>3)?0:i+1;a("1");},5000);
</script>

<div>
<img id=i0 src="img0.jpg" style="opacity:1">
<img id=i1 src="img1.jpg">
<img id=i2 src="img2.jpg">
<img id=i3 src="img3.jpg">
<img id=i4 src="img4.jpg">
</div>​
```

Comment: I used the same code but it is showing the error as document.getElementById("slide") returing null !!